# No Resource Identifier found for attribut 'layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf' in package (APT0000) Xamarin ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, constraints

I try to create layout with Constraint.Layout in xamarin android in Visual Studio for Mac. 
I Have added nuget package for Constraint.Layout & Constraint.Layout.Solver

[image]

And layout have -> *xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"*

But I always get error that say

> 'No Resource Identifier found for attribut
>   'layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf' in package (APT0000)'.

When I run the app.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

ConstraintLayout comes under `Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout` packges.

You must install it from nuget packge manager to use Contraint.Layout.

Your layout should look like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contraint_Activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]